# Can't enable a queue with 5 messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I'm working with SQL Server Express 2012 and I have a Queue.

When I run this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *, casted_message_body = 
CASE message_type_name WHEN 'X' 
  THEN CAST(message_body AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
  ELSE message_body 
END 
FROM [TRZIC].[dbo].[AsyncExecQueue] WITH(NOLOCK)
```

I get five rows.

I made the following script only to empty the queue. But, when I run it:

```
declare @h uniqueidentifier
        , @messageTypeName sysname
        , @messageBody varbinary(max)
begin try
receive top(1)
    @h = [conversation_handle]
    , @messageTypeName = [message_type_name]
    , @messageBody = [message_body]
    from [AsyncExecQueue];
end try
begin catch
declare @error int
            , @message nvarchar(2048)
            , @xactState smallint;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
            , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            , @xactState = XACT_STATE();

        raiserror(N'Error: %i, %s', 16, 1, @error, @message);

end catch
```

I get an error with the following message:

`Error: 9617, The service queue "AsyncExecQueue" is currently disabled.`

Then I enable the queue on SQL Management Studio, but I refresh SQL Management Studio pressing F5 and then the queue is disabled.

Is there any problem? I want to empty the queue.

Comment: Have you set your queue to remove recieved messages, and if not does the messages in the queue have status 3 (Retained sent message)?

Comment: All messages has status 1. I don't know if I set on my queue to remove received messages. It is my first time working with queues on SQL Server. On queue properties, I see that 'Is retention enabled' is false.

Comment: Maybe the rows are locked and you added `NOLOCK` (which is very unsafe!).

Comment: Or there was an exception which you swallowed with the empty catch. Is this production code? Don't swallow in production code.

Comment: And r u sure you run RECEIVE in [TRZIC] database?

Comment: @usr No, this is not production code. That is a test to empty the queue. I'm trying to demonstrate that I can't empty the queue.

Comment: Why is the catch even there? Maybe an exception occurred. Remove it to be sure. After all you have to start somewhere with your investigation.

Comment: @usr Because I need begin try and begin catch to run the script on SQL Management Studio.

Comment: I have updated my question with better code and more details. Thanks!

Comment: @VansFannel very helpful to know that there is actually an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[If the queue is disabling itself, it's almost always an issue with poison messages.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171592%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) These are messages that the activation sproc cannot process, puts back onto the queue (with a `ROLLBACK` in a `CATCH` block), and then continually tries to reprocess.  If this happens enough times (5), the queue gets disabled to avoid an endless processing loop.

You should [`ALTER` your queue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189529.aspx) to enable it and remove the activation procedure ( `...STATUS = ON, ACTIVATION (STATUS = OFF...` ) so it won't process automatically, then you can run your manual test.